# Base64 enconding and decoding a byte[] to String gives different results

Tags: java, arrays, encoding, decoding

so I'm currently trying to save a byte[] to a .txt file and then retrieve it while encoding it and decoding it with Base64 (It is a byte[] with 16 length). I've tried this code:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

However, when I print **bytes** before and after encoding the result is never the same, I've looked in other forums/questions and I can't find the issue here, I would appreciate a little help here.

Comment: And how you print it? If with `bytes.toString()` then obviously it would be different(as it's not the same instance of bytes array) but the content should be the same.

Comment: I was printing it through an API that apparently uses `.toString()` method, I got it fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are printing the values of the array and not using the toString() method of the array. toString() returns the object's hash code, which has nothing to do with the values of the array.

If you would like to convert the bytes into a String, use the String(byte[]) constructor, or you can use Java's Arrays.toString(arr) method to print out the bytes as seen [here](http://tpcg.io/Sm9VqLdw).

Comment: Thanks! I was using an API to print the value of it, and apparently the API automatically applies `.toString()` method to it, I could fix it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
byte[] bytesBefore = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes( bytesBefore );
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( bytesBefore );
byte[] bytesAfter = Base64.getDecoder().decode( encoded );
if( bytesBefore.length == bytesAfter.length )
{
  for( int i = 0; i < bytesBefore.length; ++i )
  {
    if( bytesBefore [i] != bytesAfter [i] ) System.out.printf( "Not equals! %d != %d - index %d%n", bytesBefore [i], bytesAfter [i], i );
  }
}
else System.out.println( "Arrays have different length" );
```

and post the outcome. Because both arrays should be equals.

Comment: This one works too, I already fixed it with another solution though, thanks!